# View image of each record from two tables Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm newbie with cakephp...and I've a big question!
I've two tables

```
Users
- id
- name

Photos
- id
- title
- id_user
```

Now in the UsersController I've

```php
  public function index() {
   $this->set('user', $this->User->find('all'));
  }
```

and in the view

```php
<?php foreach($user as $post): ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['User']['name'],""); ?><h1>
<p><?php echo $post['User']['id']; ?><p>
<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to view the picture of the User near his name...for example

```php
<?php foreach($user as $post): ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['User']['name'],""); ?><h1>
<p><?php echo $post['User']['id']; ?><p>

<p>PHOTO <?php echo $photo; ?><p>

<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot
Alessandro

Comment: How do the models look like? Are they joined?

Answer (score 1):

change `id_user` into `user_id` in photos table.

In your User model add the following relationship:

```
  public $hasOne = array(
        'Photo' => array(
            'className' => 'Photo',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
```

In UsersController change function index as below:

```
  public function index() {
        $this->set('user', $this->User->find('all', array(
                    'contain' => array('Photo'))));
    }
```

Finally change you view as below:

```
<?php foreach($user as $post): ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['User']['name'],""); ?><h1>
<p><?php echo $post['User']['id']; ?><p>

<p>PHOTO <?php echo $this->Html->image($post['Photo']['title']); ?><p>

<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note: I assumed that you have image path in title field of photos table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the image name in the database, you'd do something like the following:

```
<p><img src="<?php echo '/app/media/'.$post['User']['photo']; ?>" /></p>
```

If you're wanting to store the image as the user id, do:

```
<p><img src="<?php echo '/app/media/'.$post['User']['id']; ?>.jpg" /></p>
```